# Problem with Leibniz Rule (Differentiation under the integral sign)

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

I was fooling around by differentiating some functions under the integral sign, and I seem to have stumbled on a problem I don't quite understand. There is another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/108145/448779) which asks something similar at the end, but the answer doesn't address it.

Consider the following integral: $$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(k x)}{x} \text{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(u)}{u} \text{d}u = \pi,$$

where I've used the substitution $u=kx$. Clearly, this integral is independent of $k$, and so $$\frac{\text{d}I}{\text{d}k} = 0.$$

However, if I use differentiation under the integral sign:

$$\frac{\text{d}I}{\text{d}k} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\left( \frac{\sin(k x)}{x}\right) \text{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(k x) \text{d}x,$$

where I have used Leibniz's Integral Rule, since the sinc function in the integral is continuous, and the integral converges. (Are there any assumptions that I'm missing here?) The problem is that this seems to imply that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(k x) \text{d}x = 0,$$

which doesn't make sense! (Does it?) I study physics, so I have a habit of being slightly sloppy with mathematics. It wouldn't surprise me that there's some assumption that needs to be satisfied when differentiating under the integral sign that this function does not satisfy, but I can't figure out what it is. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I have a slightly better idea of what I'm doing wrong, but I'm still not completely comfortable with it.

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(k x)}{x} \text{d}x = \begin{cases} \,\,\pi& \quad k>0 \\-\pi& \quad k<0\end{cases} = \pi \,\, \text{sgn}(k),$$

where $\text{sgn}$ is the signum function. Using the fact that $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}k} \text{sng}(k) = 2 \delta(k),$$ I get that

$$\frac{\text{d}I}{\text{d}k} = 2\pi \delta(k),$$ and so

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(kx)\text{d} x = 2\pi \delta(k),$$

which seems to be the real part of the well known relation

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i k x} \text{d}x = 2 \pi \delta(k).$$

So it looks like this might make sense if I think in terms of distributions. I'd appreciate any further input, though.

Comment: $u$ is not independent of $k$.....so $I$ is also not.

Comment: @SaketGurjar I really don't think that's true. As far as I know, the integral is $\pi$. Could you show me how it depends on $k$?

Comment: Consider : $f(x,y)=\sin(xy)$. Now if you use the substitution $u=xy$, $f(u)=\sin{u}$. Now think....is $f$ independent of $x$ due to this substitution?......$u$ still depends on $x$

Comment: The integral of the cosine over the real axis doesn't exist in the usual way, but why doesn't it make sense that if it is anything, then it may as well be $0$?

Comment: What I'm saying is that before the step where you wrote $\frac{dI}{dk}=0$, you claimed that "clearly this integral is independent of $k$".....this is what I feel is not true

Comment: @SaketGurjar You're right, I just realised that it depends on the sign of $k$, but I still think that your argument was a little simplistic.

Comment: I agree with @Allawonder ... Look up the rule for differentiation under the integral sign.  See what the hypotheses are.  It cannot give you a divergent integral like $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(k x) \text{d}x$$ as the answer, can it?

Comment: @GEdgar That's exactly my question. I can't see anything wrong with what I've done, though I'm beginning to get an idea.

Comment: I don't think you have done anything wrong in differentiating the integral as you have shown....its just that i dont think its going in the direction of calculating the integral.

Comment: @Allawonder I've realised something that I missed before, and it seems to be a little less problematic now. I've edited the question, but I'm still not completely happy with it.

Answer (score 3):

Let's follow [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) explanation of integration under the integral sign.

Consider
$$
I_{A,B}(k) := \int_A^B \frac{\sin{kx}}{x}\;dx, \qquad k>0 .
$$
We will have to do limits $A \to -\infty$ and $B \to +\infty$ afterward.

We get
$$
\frac{d}{dk}\;I_{A,B}(k) = \int_A^B \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial k}
\frac{\sin{kx}}{x}{}\right]\;dx = \int_A^B\cos(kx)\;dx
$$
**BUT** these limits all fail exist:
$$
\lim_{A \to -\infty, B \to +\infty}\frac{d}{dk}\;I_{A,B}(k) \\
\lim_{A \to -\infty, B \to +\infty}\int_A^B \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial k}
\frac{\sin{kx}}{x}\right]\;dx\\
\lim_{A \to -\infty, B \to +\infty} \int_A^B\cos(kx)\;dx
$$
So the assertion that they are all equal is not much help.

Now, this limit does exist
$$
\lim_{A \to -\infty, B \to +\infty} I_{A,B}(k)
=\lim_{A \to -\infty, B \to +\infty}\int_A^B
\frac{\sin{kx}}{x}\;dx
$$
But (as we see here) you cannot use this **phony rule**
$$
\frac{d}{dk}\lim_{A \to -\infty, B \to +\infty} I_{A,B}(k)
=\lim_{A \to -\infty, B \to +\infty} \frac{d}{dk}I_{A,B}(k)
$$
It can easily fail!

Comment: Great! This actually answers my question as to what was wrong (I had a suspicion it had something to do with limits). But if you take the definition in the Wikipedia page you've linked, what exactly is it in the **statement** of the theorem that is not satisfied?

Comment: $f(x,k)$ is continuous, $f_x(x,k)$ is also continuous in both $x$ and $k$, and $A$ and $B$ being constants satisfy the other conditions. As you've shown, using the Leibniz rule here isn't valid, but does that mean that the linked theorem is incomplete? Do we also need that $f_t(x,t)$ be continuous, perhaps?

Comment: The theorem on that page is for $A$ and $B$ finite.  Not $\pm \infty$.  By writing this with $\pm\infty$ on there, you implicitly assumed (incorrectly) that the limit of the derivative is the derivative of the limit.

Comment: I see, it doesn't seem to be explicitly specified though, but I think I understand. Thanks! Just one further question if you have the time: could you take a look at my edit above? It seems like if I think of differentiation in the sense of distributions, I seem to get something that is plausibly sensible. What do you think?